# Overriding the "email" attribute on Notifiable Trait Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email

I'm trying to use the Notifiable Trait of Laravel in a Model which doesn't have an **email** attribute (It has a **payer_email** in fact)

so I went deep inside in **Notifiable** trait code and found it uses an **routeNotificationFor** method from **RoutesNotifications** Trait so I decided to override it for my desired behavior.

The original method code is:

```
    public function routeNotificationFor($driver)
{
    if (method_exists($this, $method = 'routeNotificationFor'.Str::studly($driver))) {
        return $this->{$method}();
    }

    switch ($driver) {
        case 'database':
            return $this->notifications();
        case 'mail':
            return $this->email;
        case 'nexmo':
            return $this->phone_number;
    }
}
```

and I overrided it in my **Payment Model** in this way:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use App\Notifications\PaymentNotify;

class Payment extends Model
{

    use Notifiable;
   
    public function routeNotificationFor($driver)
    {
       if (method_exists($this, $method = 'routeNotificationFor'.Str::studly($driver))) {
           return $this->{$method}();
       }

       switch ($driver) {
            case 'database':
                return $this->notifications();
            case 'mail':
                return $this->payer_email;
            case 'nexmo':
                return $this->phone_number;
       }
    }
}
```

But when I test it, does not work. (I've used Notifiable trait on others two models and it works, without the override...)

Comment: Out of interest, try putting a `dd($driver);` *just inside* the `if (method_exists(...) {` just inside statement, *before* the `return $this->{$method}();`. Does that do anything at all?

Comment: Also, I would suggest creating a `routeNotificationForMail` method in your model and returning the address you want to email from that method. Oh and in the code you've posted, you haven't changed the `return $this->email;` bit ;-)

Comment: Oh right! just copied the wrong method (original one, not my models). I will try creating the routeNotificationForMail()

Comment: Why not just make a [custom notification channel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/notifications#custom-channels)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just created a method named **routeNotificationForMail** like @Jonathon suggested and I worked like deserved.

```
public function routeNotificationForMail(){
    return $this->payer_email;
}
```

Thanks him to open my eyes, I was drowning in a glass of water...

Comment: finding out that this is the thing that made my model not send the email notifications took me like half a day